# observableList doesn't show rows in a loop for?

Tags: javafx, observablelist

[image]

I have a problem where I am hanging out several days to display the lines in an observablelist in a loop! Yet the code function very well in console! Any help would be welcome.

```
 private void showActivitiesDriver() throws IOException {
            Path path = Paths.get("Download/Cards/F__100000015956101711071539.C1B");
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            dataFileCard = new FileBlockTGD(data);
            w = new WrapperActivityChangeInfo(dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                    .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i), dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                    .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).getActivityChangeInfo().get(j));

            for (i = 0; i < dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data().getActivityDailyRecords().size(); i++) {

                w.setTheDateTime(dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                        .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).getActivityRecordDate().toString());

                System.out.println(w.getTheDateTime());

                dateActivitiesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                        cellData.getValue().getTheDateTime()));

                /*
                dateActivitiesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(
                        DateUtil.parseDateToString(cellData.getValue().getActivityRecordDate())));
                */       

                for (j = 0; j < dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data().getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).
                        getActivityChangeInfo().size(); j++) {

                    driverActivitiesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                            cellData.getValue().getTheActivity()));

                    WrapperActivityChangeInfoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                    WrapperActivityChangeInfoList.add(new WrapperActivityChangeInfo(dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                            .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i), dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                            .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).getActivityChangeInfo().get(j)));
                    System.out.println(WrapperActivityChangeInfoList);
                }

            }
            // Set data to tableview
            activitiesDriverTableView.setItems(WrapperActivityChangeInfoList);
            //System.out.println(WrapperActivityChangeInfoList.toString());
        }
    }
```

I expect to see all the lines, but just one, yet the code works nice in console.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new `ObservableList` (initially empty) in every iteration of the inner loop. This way after the `add` invocation you've got a list containing a single list. One of those lists is assigned to the `TableView` in the end. Should see a sequence of dates followed by a number of `WrapperActivityChangeInfo.toString` results **surrounded by `[]`** in the output indicating that you're printing multiple lists.

Furthermore there is no point in assigning a `cellValueFactory` in every iteration of the loop.

You need to move the list creation outside of the loops.:

```
...

WrapperActivityChangeInfoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

driverActivitiesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(
                cellData.getValue().getTheActivity()));

for (i = 0; i < dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data().getActivityDailyRecords().size(); i++) {

    ...       

    for (j = 0; j < dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data().getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).
            getActivityChangeInfo().size(); j++) {

        WrapperActivityChangeInfoList.add(new WrapperActivityChangeInfo(dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i), dataFileCard.getDriver_activity_data()
                .getActivityDailyRecords().get(i).getActivityChangeInfo().get(j)));
        System.out.println(WrapperActivityChangeInfoList);
    }

}
activitiesDriverTableView.setItems(WrapperActivityChangeInfoList);
```

Comment: thank you very much, too much staying on a code too long a new eye is always capital. it works as i want.

Comment: @geh - If this answer solved your problem, please **Accept** it by clicking the checkmark at the top. Accepting answers gives credit to those who worked hard on the solution for you and also helps future readers who may have a similar issue.